# Gzip with Amazon S3/Cloudfront Fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have a site I host on Amazon s3 and distribute through Cloudfront. I am attempting to serve gzipped files. So far I have done the following:
1) gzipped my files.

2) uploading my gzipped files to s3. I now have both the uncompressed and gzipped copies in the bucket. Example: style.css and style.css.gz are in the bucket

3) I made the files public.

4) I checked the metadata on the files and it appears that Amazon already put in Content-Type: application/x-gzip. I assume this is correct.

5) I then add the Content-Encoding by going to the metadata and adding a new piece of metadata: Content-Encoding: gzip

I thought that was all I had to do, but when I go to my webpage now it simply downloads copies of the html files instead of displaying them. Am I missing anything? Im a beginner here so anything helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Content-Type: application/x-gzip` is wrong.  The content type must be set to the actual content type of the files, e.g. `text/html`.

`Content-Encoding: gzip` is correct and is required.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried that and the pages are loading but it appears that it's still not serving the browser the gzipped format. Anything else I'm missing? Many thanks

Comment: It doesn't magically serve the gzipped content, you have to use the .gz links.  Alternately, just save *only* the gzipped copy of the file, without .gz... e.g., save the gzipped file as index.html, content-type text/html, content-encoding gzip... that is how I do it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot while googling for answers to my question I keep happening upon your answers. Would you mind taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590622/cloudfront-with-s3-website-as-origin-is-not-serving-gzipped-files?

Comment: lol, @AR7, my reputation precedes me.  Actually, I already did have a look. :)  I won't have a good opportunity to do any testing until tomorrow, but I saw nothing obviously wrong in your question ... what you are doing to let CloudFront handle the gzipping for you (the question, above, dates from before CloudFront released that feature) *should* work.