# Why aren't my JSP pages outputting a content-length?

Tags: jsp, amazon-cloudfront, servlet-filters, http-content-length

I have configured CloudFront in front of my web application that uses JSP pages, but it will not cache my page because the Content-Length header is not set.

Is there a way that I can get JSP to include the Content-Length, or do I need to do something ugly like have a filter than streams the content to determine it's length, then streams it to the response stream afterwards (setting the ContentLength header first).

Comment: According to the documentation, lacking a `Content-Length` header [does not prevent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomDroppedTCPConnections) CloudFront from caching response content.  I suspect that should probably be asking about CloudFront not caching your content (problem) rather than about how to handle missing Content-Length (attempted solution) -- see also [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Can you provide an example URL that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: I can confirm that setting a content length did resolve the issue. Any JSP page exhibited this issue until I added the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this by using a [filter](https://github.com/arnaudsj/carrot2/blob/master/applications/carrot2-webapp/src/org/carrot2/webapp/ContentLengthFilter.java) which works well for my needs, I even process the JSP first to remove whitespaces then chain the result of that into the ContentLengthFilter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Content-Length using JSP's [HttpServletResponse](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JSP/0080__JSP_Server_Response.htm)

> The response object is an instance of a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse object.
>
> We can use the following methods to set HTTP response header in your servlet program.

Call [setContentLength](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength(int)) method

> Sets the length of the content body in the response In HTTP servlets, this method sets the HTTP Content-Length header.

Comment: Thanks - but doesn't JSP already know the length of the content it's outputting to the response, so doesn't it try to set the Content-Length header itself? If not, when / where can I do it.  My initial thoughts are a filter, but this sounds like I'd have to stream the original response somewhere first because I can't write a response header before I know the length of the content (e.g temporarily in-memory/disk) then capture it's length before streaming back through the response? If not a filter then within the JSP I wouldn't know the length in advance.

Comment: @DevologyLtd maybe you missing `<AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590622/cloudfront-with-s3-website-as-origin-is-not-serving-gzipped-files

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 - but that XML AllowedHeader is for CORS Configuration with S3 buckets and I'm using vanilla JSP.